# SPLUNK enterprise i am trying to calculate results where if > 4% of failure is anomaly?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

SPLUNK enterprise i am trying to calculate results where > 4% of failure  is anomaly. is formula correct? to set anomaly ?(failcount and total count fields are numeric)

| inputlookup  sample.csv | eval isananomaly = if('Failcount' / 'Totalcount' * 100 > 4 ,  1 , 0)

Comment: Does each event in question have a Failcount _and_ Totalcount? Are these fields numeric?

Comment: yes its numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic *appears* correct, but why multiply by 100?

Save yourself a step:

```
| inputlookup sample.csv 
| eval isananomaly = if((Failcount / Totalcount) > .04 , 1 , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is correct logic

| inputlookup  sample.csv | eval isananomaly = if((Failcount * 100 / Totalcount) > 4 ,  1 , 0)

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is resolved.

Comment: @RichG - self-answered questions have a waiting period before an answer can be accepted (to encourage further (and possibly better) answers). Also: accepting an answer is by no means a requirement of the community :)